# count number of entries in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table of page hits in the form of :
`user` `timestamp` `url` and I would like to return a grouped list of URL's with a count of how many times each url has been hit.

I can group against the url easily enough but how do I return the count of hits?

I would like to return:

`url` `last user` `last timestamp` `number of hits`

I've got this far to return the last user and timestamp;

`var currentPageHits = pageHits.GroupBy(x => x.Url)
            .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.TimeStamp == x.Max(z => z.TimeStamp)))
            .SelectMany(x => x);`

I'm not sure how to add the additional column that contains the count of entries though

Comment: There is an extension method `.Count()`, so in your case `var currentPageHits = pageHits.GroupBy(x => x.Url) .Select(x => x.Where(y => y.TimeStamp == x.Max(z => z.TimeStamp))) .SelectMany(x => x).Count();`

Comment: jacqijw - that would only give me the count of the table, i'm trying to create a new column within the group

Comment: Rather than just downvoting my question it would make more sense to explain whats wrong with it.

Comment: +1 because this is my question also, I hate the people down voting without any help, at least you can say the reason or a cue to how to found answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var currentPageHits = pageHits
    .GroupBy(x => x.Url)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        LastEntry = x.OrderByDesc(y => y.TimeStamp).First(),
        NumberOfHits = x.Count(),
        Url = x.Key,
     })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        LastTimeStamp = x.LastEntry.TimeStamp,
        LastUser = x.LastEntry.User,
        x.NumberOfHits,
        x.User,
    })
```

Comment: Thank You, that's nearly perfect.